# How to create Solution file with dotnet core CLI

Tags: asp.net-core, command-line-interface

I cannot find a way to create a new solution file using the dotnet core CLI commands described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/dotnet-sln.

I ran the commands:

- `dotnet new  web -n webtrain`
- `dotnet new  classlib -n core`

after that, the projects were created correctly, but now I want to create a solution file to group them all, but I cannot find the right command to do that. Anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: you linked to the documentation that shows the command dotnet sln, if that doesn't work for you then it means you probably don't have the latest sdk installed

Comment: was an interpretation mistake. All the operations to create new things are into the `dotnet new ...` command.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

looks like you use

```
dotnet new sln --name mysolution
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/dotnet-new

Comment: thanks, was an interpretation mistake. I thought all `sln` operations would be in that `dotnet sln` commands.

Comment: As of version 2.0.0, the tool adds a `.sln` automatically, so you should just do `dotnet new sln --name mysolution`.

Comment: It adds the .sln extension regardless of whether you type it or not, so if you do type it, it adds it twice: Solution.sln.sln

Answer (score 4):

AS I've seen it's a two step operation which consists of:
1 - Creating the Solution file with "dotnet new sln --name mysolution.sln" command in the folder you need and
2 - Add your csproj file to this solution with the command "dotnet sln yourSlnFileYouCreated.sln add PathToTheCsProjFile"

You can remove and add more projects to the same solution file if you want.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/dotnet-new
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/dotnet-sln.

Answer (score 3):

First, you have to create the folder. This will be the solution name. Then run this command inside that folder:

```
dotnet new sln
```

This will create a `.sln` file in that folder.